# What happens to the Midi-chlorians when a Jedi or person dies?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, midichlorians

What happens to the Midi-chlorians when a person dies? In Star Wars the Midi-chlorians are alive, but do they need a host or do they die with the being?

Comment: In Legends they 'migrate' into the Force: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian/Legends

Comment: They react with Midi-waterians to form Midi-hydrochloricacidians, and dissolve the body.